# Null check for React.MutableRefObject<null>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an Input that I pass down to a child component. I am trying to focus on the input from the child component. I handle the input as follows in my code:

```
interface IProps {
  searchInput: React.MutableRefObject<null>      
}

const MyModules: React.FC<IProps> = ({ CurrentlyRegisteredModules }) => {
  return (
    <Button onClick={() => {
       if (searchInput && searchInput.current) {
         searchInput.current.focus()
       }}}
    >
       Focus Search
   </Button>
  )
}
```

The problem is that this line `searchInput.current.focus()` is giving me an error that says **Object is possibly 'null'** . I have tried to do some null checks before calling the line as shown in the code but it still gives me the error.

Can anyone explain to me why its behaving this way and possibly suggest how I could fix it?

I am grabbing the input from the parent component as follows:

```
const ManageModules: React.FC<IProps> = ({ history }) => {
   const searchInput = useRef(null);

   return (
     <Select ref={searchInput} onSearch={handleSearch}>
     </Select>
   );
}
```

I am using a AntD Select which uses  internally

Thank you.

Comment: Why is `searchInput` a `React.MutableRefObject<null> `?

Comment: I grabbed it using const searchInput = useRef(null); and thats what I am getting as the type for searchInput